# ImageMagick convert -set comment not working

Tags: image, metadata, imagemagick-convert

I'm trying to add a comment to an image with convert.

I've tried the following with a PNG but they don't seem to work

```
convert input.png -set comment "my comment" output.png
convert input.png -comment "my comment" output.png
```

[image]
[image]

Any ideas why?

Comment: Where are you expecting to see the comment in the images above? "This option sets the comment meta-data of an image " I assume you need to check the EXIF data

Comment: You can see the comment if you then do `identify -verbose output.png` or `identify -format "%c" output.png`

Comment: hi guys, many thanks for your replies. From the sounds of it then, I assume I have a poor understanding of the issue. Taking a step back, what I want to achieve, is to embed some info in the image (I guess ideally without editing the exif data), where no mater what the OS or the image file format, someone could read a message/copyright info when they go to the file properties. Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Windows has almost no support for reading metadata in PNG files.  The only piece of metadata that Windows does read is the `PNG:CreationTime` tag, which it uses to fill the "Date Taken" property.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply @StarGeek. I assume, like I said to the thread above, I have a poor understanding of the issue. Taking a step back, what I want to achieve, is to embed some info in the image (I guess ideally without editing the exif data), where no mater what the OS or the image file format, someone could read a message/copyright info when they go to the file properties. Is that possible?

Comment: For a PNG file, no.  As I mentioned (and you can see in your Windows properties image), Windows only reads the one item.  I can't speak as to what a linux or Mac will show. So they would have to use some other software to find it. One option might be to convert the PNG to a TIFF, which would be a lossless operation. You could then use the `XMP:Description` tag, as well as others, to hold your data. TIFF has widespread support among most programs, with the major exception of web-browsers, such as Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Just format command didn't work for me. I had to do the following:

```
identify -verbose -format "%c" image.png
```